# "hmmlearn" TypeError: ufunc 'log' not supported for the input types,

Tags: python, hmmlearn

I use hmmlearn to decode.

Hidden state has six topics and observations are 345 words.

start_probability is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzJZd.png)

transition_probability is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uS8Hw.png)

My code is:

```
model = hmm.MultinomialHMM(n_components=n_states)
model.startprob_= start_probability
model.transmat_ = transition_probability
model.emissionprob_ = np.array(emission_probability)

X_seq = np.array([X]).T

logprob, topic = model.decode(X_seq, algorithm="viterbi")
print("Word Sequence:", ", ".join(map(lambda x: observations[x],X)))
print("Ttopic:", ", ".join(map(lambda x: states[x], topic)))
print(logprob)
```

But I got the error "TypeError: ufunc 'log' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe'' "

Comment: Please provide the full traceback of the error and avoid using images (copy/paste the values). As a side note, the initialization values are too biased. The transitions are forced to some states with probability 1, so is the initial state. Initialize these values randomly. Finally, the model is not trained here, is it expected? Do you train it on your data beforehand?